# UI is not appearing, xserver-xorg-video-intel not installed properlly?

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, xserver

I am new to Ubuntu , yesterday I have install OS , after that I have install some pakages like JAVA, VLC etc . Now I am not getting the UI. but yesterday(after installing OS) I worked with the help of UI only. Some one suggest that after installing `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, have to restart the system but I didnt do that. to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` I did fallowing steps in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

The problem is I am getting only black screen like terminal. is this the problem of `xserver-xorg-video-intel`? please help me to get the UI.

Comment: the same problem (https://askubuntu.com/questions/561049/ubuntu-14-10-freeze-at-boot-after-upgrade-intel-graphics-xorg-xserver-etc)! Did you solve it?