# Ubuntu 14.10 freeze at boot. After upgrade intel graphics (xorg-xserver etc)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, xorg, intel-graphics

For the last week I fully reinstall Ubuntu about 4 times. I fed up of this - so I cry for help!

Whatever I tried nothing work: purge and reinstall ubuntu-desktop, nvidia-drivers, xorg-xserver and so and so on.

Please, see the screenshot for more information at the moment when Ubuntu freeze (while booting)

[image]

The last actions were to add ppa:xorg-edges and install the latest packages, but unfortunately it doesn't help - result the same as before - black screen. However for now messages appear immediately after freezing.

**UPDATE:** I don't know how to solve it and the answer is proposed I accepted only because there is no workaround ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xorg-edgers are known for potentially breaking systems.  You will need to boot into one of the recover modes (the one with networking available) and remove that package:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To get into the recovery mode, hold the left shift key down at boot time so that you see the Grub menu - choose the recovery option, and choose a terminal with network capability.  This does take a short while to load and become operational.

Comment: This problem was before installing packages from xorg-edgers, I don't think it helps, but still, give me a little time I try it..

Comment: Unfortunately - it doesn't work(

Comment: Ah - I had read that your last action was to install the xorg-edgers.  Your system worked before that?

Comment: nope, It happened after upgrading through `apt-get upgrade`, but after some "fresh install"s I realized that the problem appears after upgrading `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package..

Comment: I'm looking through several posts reporting the same issue on other forums - which version of the kernel are you running?

Comment: my kernel is 3.16.0-25, I searched too - it seems like problem is new if look at the date.

Comment: Looks like it to me also, and related generally in some way to an intel driver.  I'm running 3.16.0-28 and have not experienced this problem.

Comment: Can I upgrade my kernel to the 3.16.0-28?

Comment: I don't know why not - it was in an update package last week.

Comment: Ok, I try something to break down my system completely =)) and if it works or not - I say you)

Comment: After some downgrades of some packages and upgrading the kernel to the last one - I just reinstalled Ubuntu again. I don't know how to solve it if this problem appears again.